# for frontend using javascript using algolia api how can i disabled highlighter

Tags: javascript, algolia

I am using Algolia API for search when I am search it's giving me result but it highlight the text I don't want to be highlighted text

```
const search = instantsearch({
indexName: 'testing',
searchClient,
routing: true,
attributesToHighlight: [],
searchFunction(helper) {
    const container = document.querySelector('#hits');
    container.style.display = helper.state.query === '' ? 'none' : '';
    helper.search();
  }
});
search.addWidgets([
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#show_search_list',
    placeholder: 'Search for Email',
    showReset: false,
    templates: {
      submit: 'GO',
    }
  })
]);
search.addWidgets([
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits',
    templates: {
    item: 
    `
     <p>{{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "full_name" }{{/helpers.highlight}}</p>
    <p>{{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "email" }{{/helpers.highlight}}</p>
     `,
     empty: `We didn't find any results for the search <em>"{{query}}"</em>`,
    },
    })
   ]);
```

I read documentation but not found anything related to my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I found it and I Changes this {{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "full_name" }{{/helpers.highlight}} to this {{full_name}} and its work fine as helpers.highlight make the attribute highlighted. now it's works fine for me